# Align Tree Panel to the Center or right

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic

Fairly new to ExtJS 6, how do I align the tree panel to the center or right of the panel. Been trying to do this for weeks. Please assist

Comment: By aligning tree panel you mean tree panel items? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes the items inside, it seems by default, the items are aligned to the right and it its a columns, I have to say (align: 'left') but I don't know how to align left for a tree panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what API Docs say:

> By default a TreePanel contains a single column which uses the text Field of the store's nodes.

You might declare the [tree column](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.tree.Column.html) with the `text` dataIndex and the specify the align:

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        dataIndex: 'text',
        flex: 1,
        align: 'end'
    }]
});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22tu.

Not sure if you are trying to align only certain components or all of them. If the latter is the case, you might want to take a look at Sencha's ["Right-to-Left Support in Ext JS"](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/core_concepts/rtl.html) guide.

Comment: How do I do that?